# "Class 'Swift_Mailer' not found"

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I got this error, but class Swift_Mailer exists in MailServiceProvider.php

> "Class 'Swift_Mailer' not found" on line 95 of /home1/phloxmar/phloxcms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php

here's my MailServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Mail;

use Swift_Mailer;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MailServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerSwiftMailer();

        $this->registerIlluminateMailer();

        $this->registerMarkdownRenderer();
    }

    /**
     * Register the Illuminate mailer instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerIlluminateMailer()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('mailer', function ($app) {
            $config = $app->make('config')->get('mail');

            // Once we have create the mailer instance, we will set a container instance
            // on the mailer. This allows us to resolve mailer classes via containers
            // for maximum testability on said classes instead of passing Closures.
            $mailer = new Mailer(
                $app['view'], $app['swift.mailer'], $app['events']
            );

            if ($app->bound('queue')) {
                $mailer->setQueue($app['queue']);
            }

            // Next we will set all of the global addresses on this mailer, which allows
            // for easy unification of all "from" addresses as well as easy debugging
            // of sent messages since they get be sent into a single email address.
            foreach (['from', 'reply_to', 'to'] as $type) {
                $this->setGlobalAddress($mailer, $config, $type);
            }

            return $mailer;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set a global address on the mailer by type.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer  $mailer
     * @param  array  $config
     * @param  string  $type
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setGlobalAddress($mailer, array $config, $type)
    {
        $address = Arr::get($config, $type);

        if (is_array($address) && isset($address['address'])) {
            $mailer->{'always'.Str::studly($type)}($address['address'], $address['name']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the Swift Mailer instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerSwiftMailer()
    {
        $this->registerSwiftTransport();

        // Once we have the transporter registered, we will register the actual Swift
        // mailer instance, passing in the transport instances, which allows us to
        // override this transporter instances during app start-up if necessary.
        $this->app->singleton('swift.mailer', function ($app) {
            return new Swift_Mailer($app['swift.transport']->driver());
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the Swift Transport instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerSwiftTransport()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('swift.transport', function ($app) {
            return new TransportManager($app);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the Markdown renderer instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerMarkdownRenderer()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__.'/resources/views' => $this->app->resourcePath('views/vendor/mail'),
            ], 'laravel-mail');
        }

        $this->app->singleton(Markdown::class, function ($app) {
            $config = $app->make('config');

            return new Markdown($app->make('view'), [
                'theme' => $config->get('mail.markdown.theme', 'default'),
                'paths' => $config->get('mail.markdown.paths', []),
            ]);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            'mailer', 'swift.mailer', 'swift.transport', Markdown::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

I already tried composer dumpautoload but error still exists.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? Have you recently upgraded your version?

Comment: Explain what you try to archive. From your code it looks like you try to setup a Markdown mailer. Laravel has this already built-in. Please read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#markdown-mailables

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are importing the class properly you should check in your autoload if you are requiring something like this:

```
 require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php';
 Swift::registerAutoload(__DIR__.'/../vendor/swiftmailer/lib/swift_init.php');
```

If you do not have these try to add them and run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question, I already did that before, in my localhost i've got no error sending the contact form page, then after i uploaded it in hosting which is bluehost I got that error